# Waiting for installer process to complete inside Isolated Environment

Tags: uwp, desktop-app-converter

I am trying to convert .msi to .appx using Desktop App Converter. But at one point I got the below statement after which nothing happens.
**Waiting for installer process to complete inside Isolated Environment**

This the command I have used in DAC :

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer "C:\Users\akshay.verma\Desktop\Folens UWP\13_08_2019\Setup\Setup.msi" -InstallerArguments "/quiet" -Destination C:\Output\MyApp -PackageName "FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE" -Publisher "CN=29ART5E3-HH9B-7873-8E62-699GF5689FA0" -Version 2.2.4.0 -MakeAppx -Sign -Verbose -Verify
```

I tried to change the InstallerArguments to /quiet/S/SILENT/VERYSILENT/qn
but none of them works.

In log file I am getting this :

```
VERBOSE: Running installer command in Isolated Environment
VERBOSE: Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /quiet DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 INSTALLSTARTMENUSHORTCUTS=1
/norestart /i "C:\shared\installer\Setup.msi" /l*v "C:\shared\logs\install_Setup.log"
VERBOSE: Waiting for installer process to complete inside Isolated Environment
```

if I am running the below command separately in cmd then my msi is successfully getting installed without any user interaction.

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /quiet DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 INSTALLSTARTMENUSHORTCUTS=1
/norestart /i "C:\shared\installer\Setup.msi" /l*v "C:\shared\logs\install_Setup.log"
```

**Please help me to resolve why DAC is getting stuck.**

Comment: Could you share more detail about your os version and  DAC  version?

Comment: OS Version : 10.0.18362
DAC Version : 2.1.4.0

Comment: The Desktop App Converter tool is deprecated. We recommend that you use the  [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package-msi-vm) instead.

Comment: MSIX Packaging tool will not support lower version of windows 10 and I need to support all the verisons of windows 10. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Your application installation requires user interaction. Your application installer must be able to run silently, and it must install all of its prerequisites that aren't on by default on a clean OS image For more please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT My application installer is successfully able to run silently If I am running the below commmand separately in cmd. But when the same command is getting executed from DAC then  it is getting stuck.
The command is :
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /quiet DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 INSTALLSTARTMENUSHORTCUTS=1
/norestart /i "C:\shared\installer\Setup.msi" /l*v "C:\shared\logs\install_Setup.log"

Comment: From case description,  your command looks correct, you could also try to use VERYQUIET installargument, I suppose your DAC does not run in the correct environment, please try to convert the app in other machine to exclude this.